# I have two columns, i want the second column to have the same height as the first column always

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two columns, i want the second column have the same height as the first column always, if the first column grow or shrink the second column follow the height(I got this result with javascript, but I just wanted to css)

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

```js
function pushInput () {
  var mainColumn = document.querySelector("#main-column");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  mainColumn.appendChild(input)
};
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="item" id="main-column">
    <button onclick="pushInput()">+</button>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>
```

[Current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFF1U.jpg)

[Desired scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaLlc.jpg)

[Desired scenario when column grow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9BuI.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, is my first time, i inserted a example

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to accomplish this with flexbox!

Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.